# Active Android many-to-many relationship

Tags: android, sql, activeandroid

Although this question is about ActiveAndroid, anyone who is familiar with ORMs could probably answer this question.

ActiveAndroid doesn't seem to give you a way to do many-to-many relationships out of the box. What I found while searching for a solution was this GitHub issue: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/46

I understand that it's explicitly creating the relationship table, but I don't understand how the following part is supposed to do anything useful:

```
public List<Foo> foos() {
    return getMany(Foo.class, "FooBar");
}
public List<Bar> bars() {
    return getMany(Bar.class, "FooBar");
}
```

This would result in a query like `SELECT * FROM Foo where Foo.FooBar = FooBar.Id;`. This would return at most one `Foo` row. Am I missing something?

Don't you need a query involving a join?

Comment: Here is my answer on another place: [Activeandroid Many-to-many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207948/activeandroid-many-to-many-relationship/39203783#39203783)

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you want to select all Foos for one specific Bar, you would do this:

```
List<Foo> foos = ((Foo) new Select().from(FooBar.class)
                .where("Foo = ?", this.getId())
                .executeSingle()).foos();
```

Comment: Is this supposed to go in Bar.java?

Comment: @Waclock, yes. And I suppose, there should be cast to `FooBar`.