# Follow up on Many to Many relationships with Active Android

Tags: java, android, sql, activeandroid

This question is a follow up the question found here: [ActiveAndroid Many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207948/activeandroid-many-to-many-relationship)

I have been working on querying my join table following along with the best answer from the above question, but I can't get it to work with my specific project.

I am building a twitter-clone project as a practice project. I want to have a Many to Many relationship between tweets and hashtags.

Here is my join table:

```
@Table(name = "tag_tweets", id = "_id")
public class TagTweet extends Model {

    @Column(name = "Tweet")
    public Tweet mTweet;

    @Column(name = "Tag")
    public Tag mTag;

    public TagTweet() {
        super();
    }

    public TagTweet(Tag tag, Tweet tweet) {
        super();
        mTweet = tweet;
        mTag = tag;
    }
}
```

I built my query in my `Tag` class:

```
public List<Tweet> getTweets() {
    List<Tweet> tweets = new Select()
            .from(Tweet.class)
            .innerJoin(TagTweet.class)
            .on("tag_tweets.Tweet = Tweet")
            .where("tag_tweets.Tag = ?", this.getId())
            .execute();

    return tweets;
}
```

This is populating `tweets` with every tweet in my database.  I only want the tweets associated to the tag that I am calling the method on.

I am assuming my query isn't being constructed properly.

Comment: i have the same problem, how did you solve this?

Comment: i found solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207948/activeandroid-many-to-many-relationship?lq=1)